# Change Tab Bar background color dynamically

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, tabbar

I would like to change Tab Bar color dynamically. I know we can change it in AppDelegate but how to do it in a view controller?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue?

Comment: No, it doesn't work... So I dont't use tabbar anymore.

Comment: Do you have tab bar controller ?

Comment: Yes, I had it. But I don't use it anymore. I use now custom segue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that inside your UITabBarView controller:

```
self.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x12ff11)
```

That will give you greenish background. If you have a reference to the `tabBarController`, you could do:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```